# Strange behaviour using Ajax post but allowed GET and Head after change from html submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, laravel-5

I have some jquery code that posts a form to upload images:

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
    $("#addimage").click(function(){
        $("#uploadimages").dialog();
    });

    $('#postimages').click(function(){
        var mydata = new FormData($("#imagesform")[0]);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'upload',
            type: "POST",
            data: mydata,
            async: false,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(){
                location.reload();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

With a form that looks like this:

```
 <div id="uploadimages" style="display: none" >
     <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="imagesform">
          <input type="file" name="my_file[]" multiple>
          <input type="submit" id="postimages" value="upload">
          <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>"/>
          <input type="hidden" name="eventname" id="eventname" value="<?php echo $event->event_name?>"/>
     </form>
 </div>
```

I have a route in my routes.php (using Laravel framework) that looks like this: `Route::post('upload', 'HomeController@upload');`

This all worked back when I still had the form submit using regular html attributes but after I added the jquery with ajax it's giving me an error saying:

> methodNotAllowed(array('GET', 'HEAD'))

It seems to be still making a POST request but for some reason now only GET and HEAD are allowed? I really don't get it, I didn't change anything except change the post of the form to jquery/ajax from purely html (needed to do that to redirect to the current page)

Comment: Synchronous Ajax requests are a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

You do not cancel the click action so the form is also submitting. That could be causing an issue.

```
$('#postimages').click(function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();
    /* rest of code */
});
```

Comment: there is no action on the form though?

Comment: The form is still going to submit.... No action means it submits back to the current page.

Comment: Oh well, it did the trick, even though I don't get it completely, thanks